# Glob + Select giving wrong file

Tags: php, html

I'm using Glob with Select to select a filename to updqte a database. Whatever file is selected  the last file from the Glob list is sent.

```
<form action = "" method = "POST">
<select>
<?php   foreach (glob("../images/activities/*.{jpg,gif,png}", GLOB_BRACE) as $filename) {
$file = end(explode('/',$filename));
echo "<option value = ".$file." > ".$file." </option>"; 
}
?>  
</select>
<input type = "submit" name="file_upload" value="Upload"  /></form>
```

The select box shows the chosen file from the drop-down list but the last entry on the list gets substituted for the chosen item. This seems to happen after the Submit button is pressed.

Comment: How are you accessing the value, the `select` has no name?

Comment: Oops! I should have included <input type = "hidden" name="filename" / > above